# How to use jqGrid with C#/ASP.NET and JSON.NET (and no AJAX.NET stuff)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, json.net

OK, I've been looking into this a few days and am not particularly sure what I am doing wrong.  If anyone has working examples of using jqGrid with C#/ASP.NET and open source tools, please, please let me know where to find them.  Any tips on finding decent documentation or tools I could use to debug this would be most appreciated too (I'm pretty new to js/jQuery).  Basically I just need the edit-in-place functionality, so if I'm overlooking another obvious solution for that, it could be helpful to know...  I'd like to avoid using AJAX.NET if at all possible.

I feel like I'm just overlooking something really obvious here.

In the following example, I do get the jqGrid to display, but it shows no data.

Here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#role_assignment_table").jqGrid({ 
        url:'http://localhost:4034/WebSite2/PageItemHandler.asmx/GetPageItemRolesJson?id=3',
        mtype: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "jsonstring",
        colModel:[
            {name:'Id', label:'ID', jsonmap:'Id'},
            {name:'Title', jsonmap:'Title'},
            {name:'AssignedTo', label:'Assigned To', jsonmap:'AssignedTo'},
            {name:'Assigned', jsonmap:'Assigned'},
            {name:'Due', jsonmap:'Due'},
            {name:'Completed', jsonmap:'Completed'}
        ],
        jsonReader: {
            page: "Page",
            total: "Total",
            records: "Records",
            root: "Rows",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "Id"
        },
        rowNum:10,
        rowList:[10,20,30],
        imgpath: 'js/themes/basic/images',
        viewrecords: false,
        caption: "Role Assignments" 
    });  
});
```

---

**The HTML:**

```
<table id="role_assignment_table" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" />
```

---

**The generated JSON:** I'm not sure if it makes it to the jqGrid, or if the jqGrid doesn't like my JSON or my WebMethod, but I can call it myself when I go to the proper URL and get the JSON result string.

```
{"Page":"1","Total":1.0,"Records":"4",
"Rows":[
{"Id":1,"Item":null,"Title":"Story Manager","AssignedTo":null,"Assigned":"\/Date(1245186733940-0500)\/","Due":"\/Date(1248383533940-0500)\/","Completed":"\/Date(1247087533940-0500)\/"},
{"Id":2,"Item":null,"Title":"Analysis","AssignedTo":null,"Assigned":"\/Date(1245186733940-0500)\/","Due":"\/Date(1248383533940-0500)\/","Completed":"\/Date(1247087533940-0500)\/"},
{"Id":3,"Item":null,"Title":"Narrative","AssignedTo":null,"Assigned":"\/Date(1245186733940-0500)\/","Due":"\/Date(1248383533940-0500)\/","Completed":"\/Date(1247087533940-0500)\/"},
{"Id":4,"Item":null,"Title":"Graphic","AssignedTo":null,"Assigned":"\/Date(1245186733940-0500)\/","Due":"\/Date(1248383533940-0500)\/","Completed":"\/Date(1247087533940-0500)\/"}
]
}
```

Cheers,
William Riley-Land

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing anything else, download and install this:

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

It will let you see exactly what is being requested and sent back by the jqGrid requests to get the JSON data.

I have some code for a working jqGrid, and here's something different:

```
datatype: "json"
```

Instead of your:

```
datatype: "jsonstring"
```

I also have a field called `colNames` which is an array of strings containing column names.

Finally, I have a `pager` field which identifies an element that will store the paging controls, and is a DIV.

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but is the JSON "text" supposed to be returned as an XML doc?  E.g. my WebMethod is returing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://localhost/WebSite2">INSERT JSON DATA HERE</string>

Comment: P.S. Thanks for the tip-on to Fiddler.

Comment: ah OK, .NET 2.0 WebMethods are XML only.  I bet that's what my problem is.  Thanks!

Comment: I have to say: this answer really helped me out before Chrome/FireFox let you watch network activity in-browser.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET, Date gets serialized as JSON ["/Date(ticks)/"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx) which can not be interpreted by jqGrid.
Possible solutions ([post](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/27/38243/)):

- write a custom formatter for the grid
- change the data we send to the grid (by sending formatted date as string)

**Please tell how did you implement date display with jqGrid ?**

Thank You.

Comment: I did it by passing a string instead of an actual date - you can still do sorting if you add "sorttype: 'date'" to that column in your colModel...

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem!  The solution I came up with is to create a custom JavaScript formatter:

```
$(this).jqGrid({  
   ...
   colModel: [
      {
      name: 'SomeDate', index: 'SomeDate', width: 100, formatter: ndateFormatter }
      }],
   ...
});


// Convert C# json Date.
function ndateFormatter(cellval, opts, rwdat, _act) {
    var time = cellval.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)\//, '$1');
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(time);
    return date.toDateString();
}
```

Comment: The above wasn't working exactly for me because my C# was generating a date like this: "\/Date(1311725560000-0700)\/".  I had to change the regex to this for it to work: var time = cellval.replace(/\/Date\(([0-9]*)(-[0-9]*)?\)\//, '$1');

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the case sensitive property **datatype** is meant to be **dataType** with uppercase **T**.

Comment: is this true?  I don't have a way to verify anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems getting jqGrid to work with ASP.NET, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723801/jqgrid-asp-net-json-is-driving-me-crazy-please-help/1173022#1173022).
This should save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks.  I eventually just switched to using XML and everything went smoothly from there.  Good write up of your discoveries!

Comment: xml will work but watch out for higher bandwidth use that the lightweight alternative json.