# jquery treegrid problem

Tags: jquery, treeview, jqgrid

how are you? now i am working with jq treegrid? it work fine with xml but when i use json then error showing in jquery.base.js as

init is not defined
[Break on this error]  init(ts);
grid.base.js (line 1137)

i can not overcome this. what is the problem??????

please any one can help me

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

- Do you have the latest JQGrid from [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6)
- Did your download include the tree grid component (you can now customize the downloaded packages)
- Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723801/jqgrid-asp-net-json-is-driving-me-crazy-please-help/1173022#1173022) to see other recommendations for working with JSON in jqgrid, and a link to a working example.