# How can I perform sorting on any column in ClientSide JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to sort my records by Column, I am using Clinet Side verson of JQGrid. Can anybnody tell me, how can I sort records in my JQGrid.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

See [jqgrid-sorting-on-client-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131280/jqgrid-sorting-on-client-side/2136367#2136367)