# programmatically sorting the jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid populated with data, but I want to change how this is shown by editing the CSS.

So far so good, but I'm trying to have a dropdownlist which, when changed, will sort the jqGrid based on the value selected.

Is there anyway to actually call the sort function programmatically?

I have tried the following which, does nothing:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{sortname: 'yearEdition,', sortorder: 'desc'});
$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Is there indeed a way to call this event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [sortGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method of jqGrid:

> Sorts the given colname and shows the appropriate sort icon. The same
>   (without sorting icon) can be done using
>   setGridParam({sortname:'myname'}).trigger('reloadGrid'). If the reload
>   is set to true, the grid reloads with the current page and sortorder
>   settings.

Comment: I accept what you're saying, however this "$("#list2").jqGrid().setGridMethod({sortname: 'Year,'}).trigger("reloadGrid");" simply does nothing.  Am I calling it wrong?

Comment: @JasonMHirst: `$("#list2").jqGrid()` is wrong! It is the same as `$("#list2")`. Probably you wanted to write comment to another answer? Please read my answer.

Comment: No, this is the correct question.  3nigma suggested I use the "setGridParam" which works (albeit the sort arrows).  You've suggested I use "setGridParam" which doesn't work; in fact there isn't even that function in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Actually @Oleg, I've just realised that I need the "Add on" from the download customisation.  Will do this and recheck.

Comment: @JasonMHirst: I suggested **to use `sortGrid` method** to sort jqGrid. I included the part of jqGrid [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) which describes *why* one should use `sortGrid` method and why another way which you use don't do the full job.

Comment: my apologies, read your messages wrong - yes I see what you're saying now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
   $("#grid").jqGrid().setGridParam({sortname: 'yearEdition,', sortorder: 
'desc'}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

here is a SO question that might help [jqGrid sorting on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131280/jqgrid-sorting-on-client-side)

Comment: Hi 3nigma, thanks, yes that 'almost' works.  Don't know if it's a bug in the jqGrid or not, but the 'sort arrows' don't reflect the new sort (i.e., they don't actually go to the column header) - is there somewhere to change this or is it a known bug?  It's NOT that important as the column headers will be hidden, was just wondering that's all

Answer (score 0):

As described by Oleg the following code will sort the grid by the `yearEdition` column, reload the grid and display the correct sorting icon:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("sortGrid", "yearEdition", true);
```

If a descending sort order is required then the `sortorder` grid parameter must also be set e.g.

```
$("#grid").jqGrid()
    .setGridParam({sortorder: "desc"})
    .jqGrid("sortGrid", "yearEdition", true);
```

Note: As described in the [API Documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) `sortGrid` is an Add On Grid method and will only be available if the correct download options were selected.

Comment: As Anthony White mentions in the comments of the jqgrid page http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods, there appears to be an undocumented last parameter for the sortGrid method, for passing the sortorder. It works for me, while passing it using setGridParam doesn't.