# Sort not working with jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've been having problems getting jqGrid to sort.  I'd like to preferable do this sorting on the client, but I'm also willing to make a new call to the database to get the sorted results as well.

I can click on the column headers and the sort arrows change directions, however the data does not change at all.

I've looked over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131280/jqgrid-sorting-on-client-side/2136367), however calling reloadGrid didn't seem to help.

My entire grid is as follows:

```
var x = $("#grid").jqGrid({
    jsonReader: { root: "rows", repeatitems: false },
    datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    autowidth: true,
    forceFit: true,
    colNames:['ID','Name'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id', key:true, index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", jsonmap:"id"},
        {name:'name', index:'name', width:90,  jsonmap: "name"}
    ],
    caption: "Results",
    loadonce: true,
    sortable: true,
    loadComplete: function() {
        jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
    }
});

//This data comes from a web service call, hard coding in to test
var jsonData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Pear'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Orange'}
];

x[0].addJSONData( { rows: jsonData } );
```

Comment: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/loading-json-data-techniques-and-sorting-issue/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you load unsorted data from the server and want just sort local data **once** you should not place `jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");` inside of `loadComplete`. The callback `loadComplete` will be called on *every* sorting or paging of local data too. Moreover it would be better to call `jQuery("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");` inside of `setTimeout`. In the case the full first loading of the grid will be finished before reloading.

I don't tested, but I suppose the correct code of `loadComplete` could be about the following

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'datatype') === 'json') {
        if ($this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname') !== '') {
            // we need reload grid only if we use sortname parameter,
            // but the server return unsorted data
            setTimeout(function () {
                $this.triggerHandler('reloadGrid');
            }, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

In the case the `reloadGrid` will be called only once at the first load of the grid from the server. At the next call the value of `datatype` option will be already `'local'`.

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop starting with the end 2014. It has many new features. One can use the option `forceClientSorting: true` to force sorting and filtering of data on the client side *before* the current page of data will be displayed in jqGrid. Thus one can just add `forceClientSorting: true` option and remove the trick, described in the old answer.

Comment: Thanks!  This makes sense.  I ended up just doing the sorting up on the server and binding new data, this was trivial and works well for my purposes.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: You are welcome! Almost any kind of implementation on the server will be quickly as sorting in JavaScript. So the sorting on the server is the best way.

Comment: I agree, especially since some of the sorting I had to do involved multiple keys; so I'd have had to figure out how to write custom comparison functions for jqGrid - which I'm sure is possible but I decided to go the simpler route for now.

Comment: should'nt it be `$this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname') == '' ` you are actually checking not equals to.

Comment: @Reddy: No. One should check whether the value of `sortname` parameter is not empty string. So one should use `===` (or `!==`) and `""` or `''`. The current code code trigger `reloadGrid` only if loaded data **need be sorted**, so only if `sortname` parameter is not empty string.

Comment: @Reddy: By the way I recommend almost always use **Strict Equality Operators** (`===` and `!==` instead of `==` and `!=`) because one typically don't want to make type conversion before comparing. You can verify that `"" == 0` and `"" == false`. The operation `==` is not transitivity: both `'' == 0` and `0 == '0'` are `true`, but `'' == '0'` if `false`!!! So I personally use `==` only in one special case `if (x == null)` which equivalent the code `if (x === null || x === undefined)`.

Answer (score 1):

Found one solution, though not entirely sure why this works.  Perhaps someone can provide a better answer.

```
var x = $("#grid").jqGrid({
    jsonReader: { root: "rows", repeatitems: false },
    datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    autowidth: true,
    forceFit: true,
    colNames:['ID','Name'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id', key:true, index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", jsonmap:"id"},
        {name:'name', index:'name', width:90,  jsonmap: "name"}
    ],
    caption: "Results",

    //Required for client side sorting
    loadonce: true,
    gridComplete: function(){ 
      $("#grid").setGridParam({datatype: 'local'}); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadonce` only works with the predefined loaders. If you use datatype as function you should set `datatype:local` manually after the first loading of the grid with the custom function.

Try something like this:

```
datatype : function (){
    $.ajax({
    …
    complete :function (…){
                …
                $("#mygrid").setGridParam({datatype:'local'});
        }
    })
},
```

Comment: You should improve this, as it might be helpfull but so far hasn't.