# Jquery grid working only for 8400 rows to load.

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Not sure what's wrong my jquery grid loading only 8400 records.
Initially I though there may be some data related Issue in tables. But I try to remove each column and tried to load entire ( around 15k ) its not loading its showing only empty grid..

```
   jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
            url: '/vunerability/GetResult/',
            //data: mydata,
            datatype: 'JSON',
            height: 250,
            width: 1150,
            rowNum: 1000,
            rowTotal: 20000,
            jsonReader: {
                root: "rows",
                page: "page",
                total: "total",
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: true,
                id: "0",
            },

            colNames: ['Vunlerability_Id','Vunlerability_Title','Security_Level','IPAddress','Operating_System','Environment', 'Location', 'Status'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Vunlerability_Id', width: 80, sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'Vunlerability_Title',  width: 100, sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'Security_Level', width: 90 },
                { name: 'IPAddress', width: 50 },
                { name: 'Operating_System', width: 100, sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'Environment',  width: 60 },
                { name: 'Location',  width: 50 },
                { name: 'Status',  width: 30 }
            ],
            pager: "#plist47",
            rowList: [1000, 2000, 3000],
            mtype: "Get",
            repeatitems: true,
            loadonce: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            autoencode: true,
            gridview: true,
            caption: "Open Results"

        });

        jQuery("#list47").jqGrid('navGrid', '#plist47', { del: false, add: false, edit: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true });

    });
```

My json Action Result

```
  public JsonResult GetResult()
        {

            var result = _db.tblVulnerabilities.Where(x => x.Status == "Open").ToList().Take(8500);
            var VunList = result
                      .Select(c => new VunerabilityViewModel.vulnerabilitylistOpenVsClose()
                      {
                          Vunlerability_Id = c.Vulnerability_Id,
                          Vunlerability_Title = c.Vulnerability_Title,
                          Security_Level = c.Security_Level,
                          IPAddress = c.AssetIP_Address,
                          Operating_System = c.Operating_System,
                          Environment = c.Environment,
                          Location = c.Location,
                          Status = c.Status
                      });
            //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(VunList);
            return Json(VunList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

can anyone help me out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't load that many rows as it's *always* going to be slow (not to mention put unnecessary strain on your server). Use pagination and/or filtering.

Comment: try doing rowNum: ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to me pure server side problem because of the usage of old ASP.NET MVC with either old `JavaScriptSerializer` for JSON serialization of because of usage very old version of `Newtonsoft.Json`. The solution will depends on ASP.NET MVC which you use and from the JSON serializer.

For example you can try to replace the line `return Json(VunList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` to the following

```
return new JsonResult {
    Data = VunList,
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
);
```

One more tip would be to open NuGet console in the Visual Studio and execute `Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json` to update to more recent version of `Newtonsoft.Json`.

There are some solution of increasing the limit of the JSON size by adding sections in `web.config`. You can search for `jsonSerialization` and `maxJsonLength`.

Additionally I'd recommend you to change `rowNum: 1000` to `rowNum: 20` or `rowNum: 25`. It has no sense to make web page many times slowly by filling the part of the page which the uses can's see without scrolling. 20-25 rows is the maximum which can display the monitor. In case of usage `loadonce: true` you will have very quick responsible page with *local* paging.

I recommend you additionally to replace `height: 250` to `height: "auto"`, which works very good if you manage the height of the grid via `rowNum`. Then you should replace `jsonReader` to `jsonReader: { id: "Vunlerability_Id" }`.

I'd recommend you to use the latest 4.13.2 version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrig - the fork which I develop. It have many new features like the usage of Font Awesome icons (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8)), the usage of `forceClientSorting: true` (see UPDATED part of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287338/315935)), the option `reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }` of `navGrid` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772720/315935)) and many other features described in the READMEs to every published version and in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).