# how to sort the jqgrid by one column

Tags: c#, jquery, jqgrid

fresh here and fresh in jqgrid .i have some problems about sorting the jqgrid by given column.please give me an example and following is  my code .

```
 function gridList() {
    var $gridList = $("#gridList1");
    $gridList.dataGrid({
        mtype: 'Get',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMonthEnrollPlanFinishRateData")',
        postData: { },

        height: $(window).height() - 128,
        colModel: [
            {
                label: "主键", name: "Id", hidden: true, key: true
            },
            { label: '真实姓名', name: 'RealName', width: 150, align: 'left' },
            { label: '本月目标', name: 'CurrentMonthPlan', width: 160, align: 'left'},
            { label: '本月招生', name: 'CurrentMonthFinish', width: 160, align: 'left' },
            { label: '完成率Hidden', name: 'FinishRateHidden', width: 150, align: 'left', hidden: true },
            { label: '完成率', name: 'FinishRate', width: 150, align: 'left' },
            { label: '状态', name: 'Status', width: 150, align: 'left' },
        ],
        pager: '#gridPager1',


        viewrecords: true,
        //sortname: "CurrentMonthPlan",
        //sortorder: "asc",
        ////pginput: true,
        ////caption: "",
        //sortable: true,
    });
}
```

Comment: which column you want to sort? tell us the column name

Comment: FinishRate ...please

Comment: Are you sure it is jqgrid? because you have mentioned "$gridList.dataGrid" instead of "$gridList..jqGrid"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to sort the grid by `FinishRate` column, then you should add `sortname: "FinishRate"` parameter of jqGrid. It will send additional parameter `sidx=FinishRate` to `url: '@Url.Action("GetMonthEnrollPlanFinishRateData")'`. By the way, I'm not sure whether you want to use XML or JSON format of data in communication with the server. You should add `datatype: "json"` if the server (`'@Url.Action("GetMonthEnrollPlanFinishRateData")'`) returns JSON data.

It's important to understand than jqGrid allows you **two alternative scenarios**: sorting, paging and filtering/searching on the server side or on the client side. If the total number of rows in the grid isn't too large (for example <1000 or <10000), then it's recommended to use client side scenario. You need just add `loadonce: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` options to the grid and to return array of all items from the server. jqGrid will automatically sort the data for you. It's important that you can use `forceClientSorting: true` option only if you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork.

If you use an old version of jqGrid or not free jqGrid, then you will have to sort the data locally or to use the trick described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287338/315935).

If you have large number of items in the grid, that you can't use `loadonce: true` and you will have to sort the data on the server based on the values of `sidx` and `sord` parameters (`sord` describes the sort direction and it has the value `"asc"` or `"desc"`).