# jqgrid reloadGrid with loadonce set to true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using two jqgrids in one page. second grid i used `loadonce: true` since i need column sort in the second grid. i need to reload both grids after a server post back. (need to show updated value in the second grid). first grid reload fine since it won't use the `loadonce` attribute. my question is can we use `loadonce` attribute and `reloadGrid` together? ( by setting `loadonce` attribute dynamically to the grid) or else do i need to go for a server side sorting in this case? please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If you use `loadonce:true` jqGrid change the `datatype` parameters to 'local' after the first load of data from the grid. All next grid reloading (sorting, paging, filtering) works local. If you want refresh the grid data from the server one more time you should set `datatype` to its original value ('json' or 'xml'). For example:

```
$("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports `fromServer: true` option of `reloadGrid` starting with the first release (starting with version 4.8). So one can use the code like

```
$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", { fromServer: true, page: 1 });
```

to do the same as above. The main advantage: such code works fine with any initial value of `datatype` (`"json"`, `"jsonp"`, `"xml"` and so on). Free jqGrid saves original value of `datatype` inside of internal `dataTypeOrg` before changing it to `"local"`.

One more helpful option of free jqGrid is the parameter `reloadGridOptions` of `navGrid`, which allows to specify default options of `reloadGrid`. Thus one can use for example

```
loadonce: true,
navOptions: { reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true } }
```

options of jqGrid, which set defaults for `navGrid` additionally. As the result the click on "Reload" button of navigator bar will reload the grid from the server instead of local reloading.

Comment: @Oleg and Sam , do either of you have any thoughts on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7093874/320399) ?  I'm trying to refresh my data from the server every 10 seconds and make sure I have the latest data

Comment: i want to convert it to local once the data is loaded , so i use    `jQuery("#memberGrid").setGridParam({datatype:'local', data:mdata}).trigger('reloadGrid');` in loadComplete but the page is not changing locally ?

Comment: @Hunt: Sorry, but I don't understand what you do and what you want to do. Do you use `loadonce: true`? Which value has `datatype` initially in your jqGrid? What is your goal?

Comment: i am trying to achieve is in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900521/remote-and-local-pagination-in-jqgid.  basically once the data is loaded after search , i want to make the pagination work locally , my datatype is `json` initially

Comment: @Hunt: I read your question before and reread it one more time, but I can't understand what you really need. If you implemented both server side paging and searching on the server side why you could need "hybrid pagination"? Your question have too many unclear things for me. You don't posted any jqGrid code and it makes interpreting of your question very difficult. The problem that jqGrid has many *alternative ways* to implement the same things. For example which kind of searching you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` or not? Do you use virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`) or not and so on.

Comment: @Migs: You are welcome! By the way you can use additionally `beforeRefresh` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3772720/315935))

Comment: @Oleg : " If you want refresh the grid data from the server `one more time` you should set datatype to its original value. " I think it works for more than one time right  ? I can continuously reload the table with this right. 

Actually the problem I had is I used `loadonce:true;` , but then I can't reload it. When I used `loadonce:false;` then reloading works, but sorting wont work. With resetting the `datatype:'xml'` when reloading this problem got solved.

Comment: @prime: Sorry, but you should describe more exactly what you do and what version of jqGrid from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use. Free jqGrid is the fork which I develop starting the end of 2014. I wrote in the UPDATED part of the answer about the option `fromServer: true`. If you use it then jqGrid reloads the data from the server everytime when the user click on Reload button of the navigator bar.

Comment: @Oleg please refer this , I posted it as a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270721/can-trigger-reloadgrid-works-when-loadonce-true-in-jqgrid

Comment: @Oleg Thank you from Turkey :)

Comment: `loadonce` with the `fromServer` option in reloadGrid is awesome!  Thanks Oleg.  This is working great for use, as the user will need new data depending on user inputer data which is passed to the server as a parameter, but then all the paging/sorting handled by the freejqGrid client, its perfect and saves a lot of server-side logic.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: You are welcome! I'm glad that you find the option helpful. I tried to implement not only large new features in free jqGrid, but to make *minor* changes, which makes the usage of jqGrid easyier. `fromServer: true` and `forceClientSorting: true` are two options, which could be very helpful in `loadonce: true` scenario.

Comment: This reloads the grid correctly but It doesn't take me to the page I have provided in parameter. Any idea ? why would this happen ?

Comment: @RohitArora: It's unclear what you do exactly. `reloadGrid` have `page` option, which allows you to load **specific** page. If you have information about the page as a parameter, you can use it as the value for `page` option of `reloadGrid`. In general you could still have some other problems. For example, jqGrid verify, that the `page` value is between 1 and the value of `lastpage` parameter of jqGrid. If `lastpage` is too small in your scenario you can need to increase it **before** calling of `reloadGrid` with `page` option.

Comment: @Oleg I have used the page parameter in reloadGrid as well. it only updates the page value in pagination - data does not get updated for that page. Data remains for 1st page.

Comment: $("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:currentPage}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{page: currentPage}]); i am doing this in version 4.4. This gets the updated data from server, reloads the grid but doesn't gets to the pagenumber which I have provided.

Comment: @RohitArora: Is it good to use version, which is 8 years old? In any way I'd recommend you to **debug** the problem (you should change from min to src version during debugging). I see many sources of the problem, which you describes. Only debugging can help here. If I guess, I can suppose that the response from the server contains `page` property with 1 instead of the requested page. In the case the value of `page` from the server response will overwrite the local `page` value.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg! Yeah I know Its old but client doesn't want it to change right now or purchase any. Finally, I debugged it and fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nice was trying for last one week , solution is perfect 
use

```
jQuery("#datalist").jqGrid().setGridParam(
    {
        datatype:'xml', 
        page:1, 
        url : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/PreviewReport?cmd=1&fromdate='+vfromDate+'&todate='+vtoDate+'&status='+vstatus+'&keyword='+vkeyword+'&mdn='+vmdn+'&filetype='+vfiletype
    }
).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

to reload the data using *`loadonce:false`*

Answer (score 0):

Just to say, for me, the following line wasn't enough, to refresh the data in my `loadonce:true` jqGrid:

```
$("#MikesGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

After calling that line, I tried to call my code which loaded my JSON data and populated the `jqGrid` with it, but it didn't refresh the rows in my grid.

My solution was to forcibly *unload* the jqGrid, and *then* call my function to recreate it.

```
$("#MikesGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

Perhaps I was just unlucky.

Btw, when I get a chance, I'll document how I wrote a generic JavaScript function to add two buttons to any jqGrid, one to refresh the (loadonce) data, and a second button to export the jqGrid data into a real Excel file, using my library:

[Export jqGrid to an Excel file](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784342/Export-Data-from-jqGrid-into-a-real-Excel-File)

I like reuseable code !

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#shoppingCatalog").jqGrid('GridUnload');
```

Will remove the structure and then your code can rebuild the grid with the data from the next server call-back.