# jqGrid with sorttype text and int in one table, does not sorted

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I have the table with some columnss.

```
Venue - text
Venue type - text
# Of Guest Rooms - integer
# Of Meeting Rooms  - integer
Max Mtg Room Sq. Ft.  - integer
Total Mtg Space Sq. Ft.  - integer
```

So problem. When I don't define "sorttype" columns  sorts only by texts fields, when I specify sorttype:int, for numeric columns they are sorted, but texts columns don't. If I specify sorttype:'text' for texts columns and sorttype:'int' for numeric, sorting occurs only by the numeric columns.

I would really appreciate any help

[Demo of my problem](http://a-venu.com/jqgrid_test.html)

Comment: Could you update the URL to the demo? The current link is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, for that this is right [link](http://a-venu.com/jqgrid_test.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove thralling commas to allow at least debug the code. The current code produce syntax error and nothing will be displayed.

For example at the end of `colModel` definition you will find `},]` combination. In the same way in `subGridOptions` you will see `false,}` combination. Moreover all `cellattr` function contains returns without `;` which isn't good. In the same way the last statement (`$("#cb_"...).attr(....)`) should be also be ended with `';'`.

Comment: I removed all thralling commas. Sorting still not working. What else could I make a mistake?

Comment: You should include `<!DOCTYPE html ...` as the first line of your HTML page. Without this the grid can't correctly displayed. The usage of `scroll: true`, `loadonce: true` and subgrids I find also very exotic.

Comment: scroll:true - i was try something, but forget what exactly ) If i understand right. I can use loadonce:true, only for datatype:local? So, i found 2 examples [your](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397671/jqgrid-reloadgrid-with-loadonce-set-to-true) or this [one](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-loadonce-problem). Which follow from them? I need this sorting (

Comment: @VaL: I recommend you to simplify your solution, make it working and only then add some additional element. The setting `loadonce:true` is *not* for `datatype:'local'`. It *changes* the `datatype` from `'json'` or `'xml'` to `'local'` after the first filling of the grid with the server data. The examples where `datatype` will be amnually set to `'local'` inside of `loadComplete` are very old (before 3.7 where `loadonce:true` was introduced). So the `sorttype` works only *after* the first load at the time when `datatype` is already `'local'`.

Comment: I followed your advice. I took from [this](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) site first example Loading Data->XML Data. applyed to my table. But sorting still only by text field as before. What can i do wrong? XML structure is identical to XML from example.

Comment: I solved my problem.
I downloaded **last** version of plugin now it 4.3 and **downgrade** jQuery version from **1.6.1** to **1.5.2**. Now all works as I expected.
Oleg, thanks for your help, and patience.