# solution for Design this forms in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I Have problem in use jqGrid,Before discussing the question of explain tables.
i have 4 tables CostType,CurrencyUnit , Request,RequestCost .
CostType Table structure

```
CostId       CostName 
-------      ----------
  1           permit
  2           Warehouse receipt
  3           Warehousing
```

and Request structure

```
RequestId         RequestNo     WaybillNo
------------------------------------------
1                    100          120Ac30
2                    101           400CA852
```

and CurrencyUnit table stracture:

```
UnitId    UnitName
------------------
1           Dollar
2           Pound
3           Rial
```

and CostRequest table stracture

```
requestId   CostId  Amount    CurrencyUnitId     Remark
--------------------------------------------------------
1             2        200      3
1             1        400      1
```

i want in fill page load grid As follows:

[image]
Afterwards user can enter request No in top textbox and click button search As follows:
[image]
 user can change or enter some Cost Amount for this request As follows:
[image]
and click in save button to save in database.
Notes: i'm starter in jqGrid i can fill first Grid other  two-step i can not implemet.
please help me . thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to answer on your question without writing the code for you.

The input field for "RequestNo" (having id="requestNo" for example) and the "Search" button could be simple controls in `<fieldset>` over the grid. `click` handler of the "Search" button can just call `$("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:1}])`. Inside of grid definition you can use `postData` like

```js
var $grid = $("#grid"),
    editingRowId,
    myEditParam = {
        keys: true,
        oneditfunc: function (id) { editingRowId = id; },
        afterrestorefunc: function (id) { editingRowId = undefined; },
        aftersavefunc: function (id) { editingRowId = undefined; }
    }; 

$grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    postData: {
        // add requestNo parameter to the request
        requestNo: function () { return $("#requestNo").val(); }
    },
    beforeRequest: function () {
        // stop request to the server for empty requestNo
        return $("#requestNo").val() !== "" ? true : false;
    },
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id !== editingRowId) {
            if (typeof editingRowId !== "undefined") {
                // save previously editing row
                $(this).jqGrid("saveRow", editingRowId, myEditParam);
            }
            // start inline editing. The user should save the row by pressing ENTER
            $(this).jqGrid("editRow", id, myEditParam);
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

You can add additionally "Save" button which would call `$("#grid").jqGrid("saveRow", editingRowId);` to save the last editing row if `editingRowId` is not `undefined`.

It is important to add `editable: true` to all columns which you want to see in editing mode. If you want to have all editing columns in the grid you can use `cmTemplate: {editable: true}` jqGrid option. It changes the defaults for column definitions defined in `colModel`.

To have dropdown in the "CurrencyUnit" column you should include additional properties in the column definition:

```js
edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "Dollar:Dollar; Pound:Pound; Rial:Rial" }
```

Comment: i Want implement Editable Inline, How to Implement this. thanks for Help me.