# how to access to dropdownlist into jqgrid and get value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

hi all i have jqgrid and set update inline . i wrote this code

```
 $(function () {

         var  localstr="2:Dolar;3:Pond;4:Rial";

 var rows;
            var lastSel;
            var grid = $('#list');



            grid.jqGrid({
                url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',

                postData: { ActionPage: 'ClearanceCost', Action: 'Fill' },
                ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
                loadonce: true,
                direction: "rtl",

                datatype: 'json',
                height: 490,
                colNames: ['RequestId', 'WaybillNo', 'CostId', 'NameCost', 'Amount', 'CurrencyTypeId ', 'Remark'],
                colModel: [
                        { name: 'REQUEST_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'WAYBILL_NO', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'COST_ID', width: 200, sortable: true, hidden: true },
                        { name: 'COST_NAME', width: 200, sortable: true },
                        { name: 'COST_AMOUNT', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'CURRENCY_ID', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select', editoptions: {
                            value: localstr
                            //,



                        },
                        { name: 'REMARK', width: 200, sortable: true, editable: true }
                       ],

                gridview: true,
                rowNum: 30,
                rowList: [30, 60, 90],
                pager: '#pager',
                sortname: 'REQUEST_ID',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'ASC',

                rownumbers: true,
                loadComplete: function () {

                    var $this = $(this);
                    rows = this.rows;
                    var l = rows.length, i, row;

                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        row = rows[i];



                        var selRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', row.id);
                        console.log(selRowId);
                        console.log(grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'CURRENCY_ID'));

                        if ($.inArray('jqgrow', row.className.split(' ')) >= 0) {
                            $this.jqGrid('editRow', row.id, true);
                        }

                    }
                },
                editurl: "jQGridHandler.ashx"

            });
            grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: true, edit: true, del: true }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false, width: 460 });


            $("#btnsave").click(function () {
                var l = rows.length, i, row;

                for (i = 1; i < l; i++) {
                    row = rows[i];

//                    var $this = grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'COST_AMOUNT');
//                    var $id = $($this).attr("id");
//                    var COST_AMOUNT = $("#" + $id).val();


//                    console.log(grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'COST_ID'));
//                    $this = grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'COST_ID');
//                    $id = $($this).attr("id");
//                    var COST_ID = $("#" + $id).val();

                   alert(grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'CURRENCY_ID'));
//                    $this = grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'CURRENCY_ID');
//                    $id = $($this).attr("id");
//                    var CURRENCY_ID = $("#" + $id).val();

//                    $this = grid.jqGrid('getCell', row.id, 'REMARK');
//                    $id = $($this).attr("id");
//                    var REMARK = $("#" + $id).val();

//                    console.log(COST_ID + ",  " + COST_AMOUNT + ",  " + CURRENCY_ID + ",  " + REMARK);



                }

            });

        });
```

i want get CURRENCY_ID drop down list value when user clicked in btn, please help me. thanks all

EDIT01:

[image]

Mr Oleg i want design like [this posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404303/solution-for-design-this-forms-in-jqgrid)

thanks for help me

Comment: Where you defined `localstr` variable? You use `+=` operation with `localstr`. What is initial value of `localstr`? `undefined`? You call `editRow` **for every row** of the grid in `loadComplete`. Why you do this? It make the filling of the grid much slowly. Typically one call `editRow` inside of `onSelectRow`. It speeds up and simplifies everithing. Additionally you use `navGrid` with `edit: true` which enable you *form editing* additionally to *inline editing*. Which editing mode you want to use?

Comment: @ oleg: in value localstr is 2:Dolar;3:Pond;4:Rial. i want when form load if coulmn editable is true change to  editable. i don't understant this- Additionally you use navGrid with edit: true which enable you form editing additionally to inline editing. Which editing mode you want to use?-

Comment: It's important to know the data which you fill in the `'CURRENCY_ID'` column. It should be values like `2`, `3` or `4` and not the texts `Dolar`, `Pond` or `Rial`. There are no the best editing mode. Sometime I use form editing sometime inline editing, but the usage of both modes like you do this makes more problems. You wrote: "i want when form load if coulmn editable is true change to editable." You mean probably that you want to start editing of all rows, but I don't understand the reason of that. I would start editing of *one* row if the user select the row and then save *the row* changes.

Comment: @ oleg : i have a form for data entry. i load all COST_NAME and i want user enter AmontCost and CurrencyType after that click in save button so i change all row to editable in start, please if this solution is not true, please give me a solution, thanks mr oleg for help me.

Comment: I suppose you mean that you have "a form for data entry" additionally to the code which you posted. Because I don't know exactly your requirements it's difficult to recommend you something. Nevertheless the call of `editRow` for *selected* row only in `onSelectRow` callback seems me still better as calling of `editRow` in the loop for *all* rows. About your main question with no dropdown list for `CURRENCY_ID` I think that *the filling* of jqGrid with data could be origin of the error. You should append your question with the JSON response from the server.

Comment: Could you post the same JSON data as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can see that you use wrong order of the columns in JSON data. The text like "EURO" are in the **third** column, but you have the column in the grid in the 6-th place. One have to count all hidden columns too. Perhaps you need just change the order of the columns and move 'WAYBILL_NO' and 'COST_ID' in another place in `colModel`.

Probably it was the error which you have?

Additionally you should not forget to define all variables which you use. For example the lines

```
var $this = $(this);
rows = this.rows;
```

should be fixed to

```
var $this = $(this),
    rows = this.rows;
```

which is the same as

```
var $this = $(this), rows = this.rows;
```

The current code do

```
var $this = $(this);
window.rows = this.rows;
```

or produce an error in strict mode of JavaScript.

Comment: @mohsen: could you post text instead of the pictures? Moreover I still don't find any values for `'CURRENCY_ID'` in the JSON and the number of column in JSON (8) still don't corresponds to the number of columns in the `colModel` (7). The values in JSON for the `'CURRENCY_ID'` must be 2, 3 or 4 to corresponds to `editoptions.value` (`"2:Dolar;3:Pond;4:Rial"`) which you use in the code.