# Implementing a Dependent jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have created a jqGrid, and in that I have a column which is a hyperlink, on click, data is fetched and a new jqGrid is created below the parent Grid.

My problem is, that when I click on any link of the parent grid, the child Grid is created successfully. But after that if I click any other link, the child grid shows the same data.

Issue is that the grid is not getting refreshed with the new data.

I have also tried `jQuery('grid1').trigger('reloadGrid')`
But this also doesn't change anything.

**EDIT**
**Below is the code which gets called onClick of the element in the Parent Grid:**

```
var dynaData2   =   getDataForWelfareStatusDetails(memberId);
           jQuery('#grid1').jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: dynaData2,
            colNames:['Effective Date ','Welfare Status ', 'State', 'IV-A/IV-E Case ID', 'Receipt No.','Case Type'],
            colMandReq:['-1','-1','-1','-1'],
            colModel: [
                   { name: 'effectiveDate',index:'effectiveDate', align:"center", editable:false,readonly:true,hidden:false, sortable:false, search: false},
                   { name: 'welfareStatus', index:'welfareStatus', align:"center", editable:false,readonly:true,hidden:false, sortable:false, search: false},
                   { name: 'stateCode', index:'stateCode', align:"center", editable:false,readonly:true,hidden:false, sortable:false, search: false},
                   { name: 'refCaseId', index:'refCaseId', align:"center", editable:false,readonly:true,hidden:false, sortable:false, search: false,formatter: returnCaseLink},
                   { name: 'receiptNum', index:'receiptNum', align:"center", editable:false,readonly:true,hidden:false, sortable:false, search: false},
                   { name: 'caseType', index:'caseType', align:"center", editable:false,readonly:true,hidden:false, sortable:false, search: false}

                   ],
            loadComplete: function() 
                {
                    jQuery('#grid1').trigger('reloadGrid');             
                },
            pager: '#pager1',
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: false,
            autoencode: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            autowidth: true,
            sortable: false,
            height: '100%',
            rowNum: 100,
            caption:""
            });
```

Any input is welcome and appreciated

Comment: can you share the code that gets called on on link clicks.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Have updated my question, kindly check

Comment: Please share the JsFiddle of ur sample code

Comment: when you want to trigger this reload?

Comment: is your data type is `json`? make sure `loadonce: false`.

Comment: @CJRamki: It is an array of JSON objects

Comment: I think this answer may help you...http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398136/2567813

Comment: @CJRamki: I am not making a server hit, the data is available in the front-end, so will loadonce: true work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50097/discussion-between-cj-ramki-and-sashi-kant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
jQuery("#grid1")
    .jqGrid('setGridParam',
        { 
            datatype: 'local',
            data:dynaData2
        })
    .trigger("reloadGrid");
```

or you could try with,

```
jQuery('#grid1').jqGrid("GridUnload");
```

SEE THIS [DOCUMENTATION](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods&s%5B%5D=gridunload)

Answer (score 1):

First of all about your main problem: Why the grid is not getting refreshed with the new data? The reason is: you try to **create** the grid `#grid1` multiple times. It's wrong. During the first call of `jQuery('#grid1').jqGrid({...});` the initial empty `<table id="grid1"></table>` will be converted to relatively complex structure of divs and tables. The second attempt to create grid from the structure will be just *ignored* and you don't see refreshing of the grid.

You can fix the code in many ways. The smallest code, but not the best one, you will get if you includes `jQuery('#grid1').jqGrid("GridUnload");`.

In any way you should remove `jQuery('#grid1').trigger('reloadGrid');` from `loadComplete` of `jQuery('#grid1')`. The callback `loadComplete` will be processed **during loading or reloading of the grid**. So you can have recursion.

Another possibility will be in separation of initial creating of the grid and the later refreshing of the grid content. With the code `jQuery('#grid1').jqGrid({...});` you can **create** the grid. To refresh the data you need 1) delete old data of the grid 2) set new data with respect of `setGridParam` for example and 3) reload the grid with respect of `trigger("reloadGrid")`.

You don't posted `onClick` part. I would recommend you to use the approach described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765086/315935) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537512/315935)) which uses `beforeSelectRow` callback instead of setting multiple `click` handles.