# jqGrid inline edit not working

Tags: json, ajax, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid and I tried to implement inline editing on the same. i could see no error but the rows are not edited and the grid will be in "saving" mode forever once i click submit button. please shed some light on where I am going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#tabl").jqGrid({
        url: "UserDetails.aspx/GetAllRecords",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            //alert(postData);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(postData));
            return JSON.stringify(postData);
        },
        jsonReader: {
            root: function (obj) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(obj.d));
                return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;

            },
            page: function (obj) { return 1; },
            total: function (obj) { return 1; },
            records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
            id: '0',
            cell: '',
            caption: "",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        colNames: ['Category', 'ParamCode', 'ParamName', 'Description', 'DefaultValue', 'CompId', 'SiteId', 'SysTerminal', 'UserId', 'LastUpdateDt'],
        colModel: [
                        { name: 'Category' },
                        { name: 'ParamCode' },
                        { name: 'ParamName' },
                        { name: 'Description' },
                        { name: 'DefaultValue' },
                        { name: 'QueryCompId', formatter: 'checkbox' },
                        { name: 'QuerySiteId', formatter: 'checkbox' },
                        { name: 'QuerySysTerminal', formatter: 'checkbox' },
                        { name: 'QueryUserId', formatter: 'checkbox' },
                        { name: 'LastUpdateDt', formatter: 'date' }
        ],
        multiselect: false,
        height: 'auto',
        autoencode: true,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        rowNum: 10,
        pager: '#pager',
        loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: "",
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, cellcontent, e) {
            pCode = cellcontent;
            jQuery("#tablParamValues").jqGrid({
                url: "UserDetail.aspx/GetParamValues",
                editurl: "UserDetail.aspx/EditParamValue",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'POST',

                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(postData));
                    return JSON.stringify({ paramcode: pCode });
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    root: function (obj) {
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(obj.d));
                        return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;

                    },
                    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
                    id: '0',
                    cell: '',
                    caption: "Manipulating Array Data",
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                colNames: ['ParamValueId', 'ParamCode', 'CompId', 'SiteId', 'SysTerminal', 'UserId', 'ParamValue'],
                colModel: [
                                    { name: 'ParamValueId', index: 'ParamValueId' },
                                    { name: 'ParamCode' },
                                    { name: 'CompId' },
                                    { name: 'SiteId' },
                                    { name: 'SysTerminal' },
                                    { name: 'UserId' },
                                    { name: 'ParamValue', index: 'ParamValue', editable: true }
                                ],

                multiselect: false,
                height: 'auto',
                autoencode: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                rowNum: 10,
                pager: '#pager2',
                loadonce: false,
                viewrecords: true,
                gridview: true,
                caption: "",
                ajaxRowOptions: {
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                serializeRowData: function (postdata) {

                    for (propertyName in data) {
                        if (data.hasOwnProperty(propertyName)) {
                            propertyValue = data[propertyName];
                            if ($.isFunction(propertyValue)) {
                                dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue();
                            } else {
                                dataToSend[propertyName] = propertyValue;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
                }

                }).trigger("reloadGrid").inlineNav('#pager2', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false },
                    {
                        ajaxEditOptions:  {    type :"POST",
                                                contentType :"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                                dataType :"json"
                                            },
                       serializeEditData: function createJSON(postdata) {
                                                if (postdata.id === '_empty')
                                                    postdata.id = null; 
                                                return JSON.stringify(postdata)
                                            },
                        closeAfterEdit: true

              }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autoSearch: true });

            //set width of grid
            jQuery("#tablParamValues").jqGrid('setGridWidth', '700');
        }
    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false })
    .jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autoSearch: true });
    jQuery("#tabl").jqGrid('setGridWidth', '700');

});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#tblData").jqGrid({
            url: "CurrencySetting.aspx/GetAllRecords",
            editurl:"CurrencySetting.aspx/EditRecord",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                //alert(postData);
                //alert(JSON.stringify(postData));
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            jsonReader: {
                root: function (obj) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(obj.d));
                    return typeof obj.d === "string" ? $.parseJSON(obj.d) : obj.d;
                },
                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.d.length; },
                id: '0',
                cell: '',
                caption: "",
                repeatitems: false
            },
            colNames: ['Cd', 'Ds', 'Culture', 'DecimalPlaces', 'ShortDescription', 'Rate', 'Symbol', 'DateTimeFormat'],
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'Cd', formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 1} },
                            { name: 'Ds', formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 2} },
                            { name: 'Culture', formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 3}, },
                            { name: 'DecimalPlaces', formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 1} },
                            { name: 'ShortDescription', formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 2} },
                            { name: 'CurrencyRate', formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 3} },
                            { name: 'Symbol', formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 1} },
                            { name: 'DateTimeFormat', formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 2} }

            ],
            cmTemplate: { editable: true },
            multiselect: false,
            height: 'auto',
            autoencode: true,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            rowNum: 10,
            pager: '#pager',
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,     
            sortable: true,
            caption: "",
            loadComplete: function () {
               // alert("OK");
            },
            loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               // alert(jqXHR.status + textStatus  + errorThrown);
                //alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false },
                            {
                            ajaxEditOptions: { type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json"
                            },
                            serializeEditData: function createJSON(postdata) {
                                if (postdata.id === '_empty')
                                    postdata.id = null;

                                return JSON.stringify({id:'AED',decPlace:'10'})
                            },
                            closeAfterEdit: true}

                            ) .jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autoSearch: true });


        //set width of grid
        jQuery("#tblData").jqGrid('setGridWidth', '700');

        $.extend($.jgrid.view, { width: 450, recreateForm: true });
        $.extend($.jgrid.edit, { width: 450, recreateForm: true });
        $.extend($.jqgrid.del, {width:300, recreateform:true});
});
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    var newWidth = $("#tblData").closest(".ui-jqgrid").parent().width();
    $("#tblData").jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidth, true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: @oleg: I have added following code to achive delete functionality on grid , but the delete webmethod is not getting invoked. what is the cause for the same. I have only edit and delete in navgrid  { ajaxDelOptions:{type: "POST", contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8",dataType: "json"},  url: "CurrencySetting.aspx/DeleteRecord",serializeDelData: function createJSON(postdata) {if (postdata.id === '_empty')
postdata.id = null;return JSON.stringify({id:'AED'})}}            
return JSON.stringify({id:'AED'}) }}

Comment: If you want to edit the code you need just click on "edit" link below of the text of the question. It's better that you post **correct code** in the question as writing bad formatted text in the comment. By the way I answered on you email just now.

Comment: @oleg Thanks a ton for pointing out the bug, I had placed type:"json", within ajaxDelOptions which was causing the issue. I have a query with regard to grid reload after add/edit/delete operations, i have set loadonce:true. with loadonce true how to achieve grid reload. followed few posts regarding the same, and understood we can use editGridRow->aftersubmit->trigger(reload), but where to place the code such that the reload event is called after edit/delete/add.

Comment: `loadonce:true` changes the original value of `datatype` (`"xml"`, `"json"` or `"jsonp"`) to `"local"` after initial loading. One have to reset the value of `datatype` to original value before reloading. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398136/315935) for more information. By the way you can use simple search on stackoverflow: [the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjqgrid%5D+reloadGrid+loadonce) and to open the first found answer to see the same post.

Comment: @oleg: I just figured out the solution, by playing around the options

Comment: Congratulations! Don't forget to think about other people. I wrote you in email that you should post your code as question. You can additionally post the answer on his own question where you describe the reason of your problem and the final solution. It could help other people.