# how to reload all jqgrids on the page after changes made in any of them

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have couple of jqgrids on a page..Now I want to reload both the jqgrids after i update a record in any of them.

Here is my body..

```
    <div style="position: relative; top: 40px; width:50%">
        <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
        <div id="pager"></div> 
    </div>

    <div style="position: relative; top: -250px; left:50%;">
        <table id="list1"><tr><td></td></tr></table> 
        <div id="pager1"></div> 
    </div>
```

and Here is the script for after submit function of first jqgrid...

afterSubmit: function (response, postdata)

```
                        {

                            if (response.responseText === "OK")
                            {
                                alert("Update is succefully");

                                alert(this);
                                $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                return [true, "", ""];

                                alert("#list1");
                                $("#list1").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                return [true, "", ""];
                                //   $(this).trigger('reloadGrid');

                            }
                            else {
                                alert("Update failed");
                                return [true, "", ""];
                            }
                        }
```

Now using this code my first jqgrid does get reloaded after updating data and shows updated data in that jqgrid, However second jqgrid which has id #list1 doesn't get reloaded/refreshed.How do I Achieve this?

Comment: now here when i use alert(this) it shows [object HtmlTableElement] ..however for alert("#list1") it shows [object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear which changes exactly you mean. If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, then the recommended way to reload the grid from the server, if it has `loadonce: true` option, would be to use `.trigger("reloadGrid", {fromServer: true})` or `$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{fromServer: true, current: true, page: 1}]);` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398136/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935)). Thus you can do the following:

```js
$(".ui-jqgrid-btable").trigger("reloadGrid", {fromServer: true});
```

If you need to trigger reloading of the grid inside of some callback like `afterSubmit` then I recommend you to wrap the above code in the `setTimeout` to allow to finish processing of the `afterSubmit` before reloading of the grid:

```js
afterSubmit: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".ui-jqgrid-btable").trigger("reloadGrid", {fromServer: true});
    }, 50);
    return [true, "", ""];
}
```

Comment: yeah i'm using free jqGrid and  it has loadonce: true but this                $("#list1").trigger("reloadGrid", {fromServer: true});   doesn't work. It's just the second jqgrid that doesnt get reloaded  my first grid gets reloaded with this code...   $(this).jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: 'json'});
                                return [true, "", ""];

Comment: @Saurabh507: Are you shure that you use free jqGrid? Which version of free jqGrid you use? (you need open `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and to see in the comment at the beginning the file: **jqGrid 4.13.1 - free jqGrid**). I recommend to load the last version from GitHub [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or to use it from CDN: see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).